# Recursive to_json in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I have a simple class that overrides to_json to list the attributes in an array -

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(a, b)
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end

  def to_json(*opt)
    [@a, @b].to_json(*opt)
  end
end
```

to_json works fine for an instance of the class -

```
irb> m = MyClass.new(10, "abc")
irb> m.to_json
=> "[10,\"abc\"]"
```

But if I put the object in an array, my custom to_json does NOT get called -

```
irb> [m].to_json
=> "[{\"a\":10,\"b\":\"abc\"}]"
```

I would expect to get the following output -

```
=> "[[10,\"abc\"]]"
```

Another example - if I create another instance that contains the first instance

```
irb> m2 = MyClass.new(20, m)
irb> m2.to_json
=> "[20,{\"a\":10,\"b\":\"abc\"}]"
```

What I expect is

```
=> "[20,[10,\"abc\"]]"
```

Looks like to_json does not get called recursively. How to solve this?

Thanks as always!!

### Updates

This seems to work as expected on Ruby 1.9.1. Thanks Mladen!
I need to use 1.8.7.

Comment: Which Ruby version you are using? It works as you expect here on 1.9.1.

Comment: That is interesting. Maybe they fixed this issue between 1.8.7 and 1.9.1.

I don't have the option of upgrading ruby on our production boxes right now so getting this to work on 1.8.7 would be great. I have found a *really bad* hack that makes it work. (1) Override to_xml instead of to_json. (2) Call to_xml, export that back to a hash and then hash to json. e.g. Hash.from_xml(m2.to_xml)["objects"].to_json.

Also I see that depending on the xml produced, the key "objects" might be something different like "hash".

Answer (score 0):

Ugly hack to get it working on Ruby 1.8.7 till someone suggests a better method:

- Override to_xml instead of to_json.
- Call to_xml, export that back to a hash and then hash to json.

e.g. `Hash.from_xml(m2.to_xml)["objects"].to_json`